# laravel 5.8 migration Base table or view already exist no need to drop table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to use migrate on laravel 5.8 but i'm getting this error message

```
C:\wamp\www\work_p\laravel\lvl1>php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view alr
eady exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id`
bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not nul
l, `email` varchar(191) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password`
 varchar(191) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timesta
mp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf
8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\wamp\www\work_p\laravel\lvl1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Dat
abase\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll
 format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make th
is exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the databa
se's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 T
able 'users' already exists")
      C:\wamp\www\work_p\laravel\lvl1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Da
tabase\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\wamp\www\work_p\laravel\lvl1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Da
tabase\Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

All solutions I found here are saying that I have to drop the tables;

But I can't I have datas on my tables I have data on my users table and on all the other tables. is there any solution to this error without drop tables ?
I did try to use this solution

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

the problem still exist

Comment: Add name of the user migration file to the `migrations` table. It'll skip running the same migration again.

Comment: did you rollback before migrating again?

Comment: Source code for the migration file would help

Comment: @Zeshan Khattak : Your solution worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to run that migration specifically, run this query on your database

```
INSERT INTO `migrations` (`id`, `migration`, `batch`) VALUES (NULL, '2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table', '1');
```